# List Year instead of month in SSRS Collapsed View

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reporting-services-2012

I have a SSRS 2012 Report with row groups as shown below. It has collapse/expand functionality.

On the collapsed view, it is displaying the first month. I need to hide the "Claim Service Month Display" (or display **YEAR** only) on the collapsed view.

How to do this in SSRS 2012?

[image]

SSRS Design Tab

[image]

Comment: Have you tried something like this on the text box expression. Have a column that returns the Year of the Claim Service (ClaimServiveYear) and then set the expression to  : =iif(InScope("Office_Group_Region"),Fields!ClaimServiceYear.value, Fields!ClaimServiceMonthDisplay.value)

Answer (score 1):

May be below image will help you -

[image]